# GnuPG with GPA & Seahorse

Tags: 13.10, seahorse

I recently installed the `GnuPG GUIs on Ubuntu, GPA & Seahorse`. Upon launching GPA the key list is populated with some keys already for what look like German companies.

When I launch Seahorse there are no keys listed at all. I wanted to check whether anyone else has installed the GPA from the repositories and found this too.

- Does GPA not look at the keys stored by GPG, or does it come
  preloaded with some keys?
- If it does look at keys from GPG, why has Seahorse not seen these
  keys too?

I've tried to look for similar issues by web search but have found nothing so far.

Thank you Ubuntu Community

J

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Gnu Privacy Assistant uses multiple backends for listing keys. For me it lists X.509 certificates and smartcards besides the GnuPG keyring.

There's no indication these keys are shipped with the package or hard coded in the software. I assume you've installed certificates using your browser or other tools which are now listed in this frontend.

Verify no keys are added to your keyring with this command run from a terminal:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked the GPG keys list and none have been added so as you say they must have been certificates from websites visited. I've tried to find out from which websites but have come up short so far.